# UICollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath row is nil

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview, nsindexpath

First time that I'm using `UICollectionView`. I'm trying to get the "row" value for each cell - to be used as an identifier/tag for the cells textfield. When `cellForItemAtIndexPath` gets called it seems like `[indexPath row];` returns `nil`. How can I get the cell index (or something else to be used as an identifier) when row is nil?

**Note**
Using iOS7, if that makes any difference...

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView  cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Returns nil
    NSLog("Row: %d", indexPath.row);
}
```

Any ideas/tips?

Comment: It does not return nil, it returns 0, for row #0!

Comment: Agreed, logging a double should never return nil. 0 != nil.and if, indeed, you have only one item in your section, then Row should log 0 for index 0. If you had 0 items in your section, you would never see this log statement as cellForItemAtIndexPath: would never be called.

Comment: Seems like you were right. Log shows 0 but `po` shows nil for some reason. Still having some problem, so I decided to create a new question since it's not totally related. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18159462/nsfetchresultcontroller-with-uicollectionview-issue-with-indexes-cells-on-update

Comment: @Anders `po` stands for "print object". Simply use `p` for primitives.

Answer (score 6):

You don't use the concept of row in a Collection View. You need to use this method from `NSIndexPath`:

```
+ (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForItem:(NSInteger)item inSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

Notice that the `row` property of a `NSIndexPath` is declared on `UITableView.h`, while the `item` property is declared on the `UICollectionView.h`