# NSFetchResultController with UICollectionView issue with indexes/cells on update and delete action

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

First time that I'm using UICollectionView, and I'm having some difficulties. Especially with updating and deleting cells (will focus on delete here, hopefully the came cause), with data from a `NSFetchResultController`. I have made a custom cell in in interface builder as part of a storyboard like this:

[image]

I have a custom `UICollectionViewCell`subclass with the following properties:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *deleteButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *containerView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *textFieldContainer;
```

In IB I have set the cell class to my custom class, connected the elements to the properties of my custom class and set the identifier to `Cell`.

In my Collection View view controller I set up the collection view and fetchResultController and relevant methods like this:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}

-  (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [self.fetchedResultsController sections][section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NoteCollectionViewCell* cell = (NoteCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}

- (void)configureCell:(NoteCollectionViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.deleteButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    [cell.deleteButton addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteNote:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [...]

    // I'm having some weird problem with this, se description below. 
    Note *note = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textField.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.textField.delegate = self;
    cell.textField.text = note.name;
    [...]

#pragma mark - Fetched results controller

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    [Default FRC method]
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
   atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
  newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    UICollectionView *collectionView = self.collectionView;

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath]];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:(NoteCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;
    }
}
```

My delete action looks like this:

```
- (void)deleteNote:(UIButton *)sender
{
    Note *note = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath  indexPathForItem:sender.tag inSection:0]];
    [[AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate].managedObjectContext deleteObject:note];
    [[AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate] saveContext];
}
```

My update action (`UITextField` delegate method) looks like this:

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    Note *note = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:textField.tag inSection:0]];
    note.name = textField.text;
    [[AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate] saveContext];
}
```

The problem(s) is as follows:

- The delete button don't always delete the right cells/object. And sometime the object/cell won't be deleted at all.
- Sometime the app crashes when I delete an object (SIGARBT error).
- Sometimes the text shows up in the wrong textfield.
- Sometimes when I delete row 0 with some text, then add press add, a new cell is added with the same text value as the previous (deleted) cell.

Any ideas on how to solve these problems would be great!

**Update**

As comment below, this log in my `deleteNote` action always returns 0 for indexPath row. Don't know if that could be the cause.

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:sender.tag inSection:0];
NSLog(@"indexPath: %@. Row: %d", indexPath, indexPath.row);
```

Comment: When you log the indexPath, is it showing the cell you tried to delete?

Comment: The following log in my `delete action` always returns 0 for the row for some reason: `NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:sender.tag inSection:0];
    NSLog(@"indexPath: %@. Row: %d", indexPath, indexPath.row);`

Comment: I would check the NSFetchedResultsController. Work your way up backwards, because I suspect it is the indexPath creating the issue.

Comment: Thanks, but I get the index path from the collectionView delegate methods (!?!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if that explains your problem, but you call

```
[cell.deleteButton addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteNote:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

*each time* in `configureCell:atIndexPath:`, so that multiple actions are attached to the
button if a cell is modified or reused. Then the `deleteNote:` would be called
more than once for one touch event.

As a workaround, you could check `cell.deleteButton.tag` to see if an action has already been attached to the button, or better:

- add the action in your `NoteCollectionViewCell` class 
  to a local action in that class when the cell is created,
- use delegation to forward the action to the collection view controller.

Comment: Seems like that was the problem. What I did was to add a `Note` (model) property to each cell, and check if it's nil in `configureCell:atIndexPath:`, and only set the selector/action if it is nil.

Answer (score 4):

You can't link a fetched results controller to a collection view in quite the same way as a table view. A fetched results controller was designed specifically to mediate between core data and a table view, so the delegate methods tie in with how a table view works.

The main difference is that a table view has a `beginUpdates`/`endUpdates` method pair that you can wrap all of the updates in. The collection view doesn't have this, you have to instead build up all of the required update calls yourself, then when the fetched results controller has finished updating, execute them all within a `performBatchUpdates:completion:` call.

There is an example implementation of this [on GitHub](https://github.com/AshFurrow/UICollectionView-NSFetchedResultsController).

Comment: I have tried to use that (twice now), but I'm having the same problem(s). I'm using iOS7, don't know if that makes any difference...

Comment: The code in your question shows no sign of that. You need to update your code to use that technique, then post the problems you're having.

Comment: Also, if I instead use `- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}` instead, I'm also getting the same problems.